# Get difference between time using strtotime returns different value

Tags: php, strtotime

I have two different time in a 24-hr format which is time in and timeout. Given the scenario below:

```
$timeIn = "19:00";
$timeOut = "09:00";
//calculated it using strtotime
$timeDiff = strtotime($timeIn) - strtotime($timeOut);
$timeDiff = ($timeDiff/60)/60;
//result is 10:00
```

With this one, instead of returning 14hrs, it returns 10hrs only. How can I catch this one out?

**UPDATE**

Thanks for the comments guys. Here is how I do it:

```
if($timeIn > $timeOut){
    $timeDiff = 24 - abs(strtotime($timeIn)/60)/60;
    $timeDiff += $timeOut;
}else{
    $timeDiff = strtotime($timeIn) - strtotime($timeOut);
    $timeDiff = ($timeDiff/60)/60;
}
```

Comment: why should it be 14 hours?? 19-9 is what?

Comment: you are doing 19 - 9 resulting in 10 if you want 14 you could change $timeIn to 23:00

Comment: Also, that won't return "10:00", but some integer instead…

Comment: maybe you want $timeOut-$timeIn? (that would need another calculation though)

Comment: 19 - 9 equals 10, nothing unusual here. you have to use datetime if you want the time between 19:00 and 9:00 the next morning

Comment: @Jeff If you will manually count it, 7PM (19:00) to 9AM is 14 hrs.

Comment: but in your question you have 9 to 19. the other way round. As I said, you want `$timeOut-$timeIn`

Comment: @Jeff Please check this line `$timeDiff = strtotime($timeIn) - strtotime($timeOut);`

Comment: How is PHP supposed to guess that those two times aren't on the same day?

Comment: @deceze answered my question, please see update.

Comment: _after you UPDATE_: you shouldn't do it that way. Now you get negative values on a normal day (eg in: 9 out: 19). a hint: you want $timeOut - $timeIn

Comment: @jeff Is 9 greater than 19?

Comment: no. It's basic maths. If you want to know the difference of two values you subtract the smaller (earlier) one from the bigger (later) one.

Answer (score 4):

Oh.. you could use datetime, as this example:

```
<?php
$timeIn = new DateTime("2019-09-14 19:00:00");
$timeOut = new DateTime("2019-09-15 09:00:00");

$interval = $timeOut->diff($timeIn);
echo $interval->h;
?>
```

Comment: Thanks fot this one. But my data has no date, so I have tried my approach and works well.

Comment: @ramj It *doesn't* work well. And without a date, those times are pretty useless. In timezones which observe DST, you may even get wrong values depending on what day those times actually are.

Answer (score 0):

You need to calculate it in timestamp, but to make the complete time you need to use full date format

Example:

```
$timeIn = "2018-09-14 19:00:00";
$timeOut = "2018-09-15 09:00:00";
//calculated it using strtotime
$timeDiff = strtotime($timeIn) - strtotime($timeOut);
```

and it gonna work

Comment: That's still a difference of 10 hours…

Comment: Reading between the lines, I think $timeOut is intended to be the following day, 15th.

Answer (score 0):

The function returning **10** hours is correct and expectable behaviour.

```
19-9=10
```

PHP doesn't know that you want to count the hours from 19:00 to 9:00 **the next day**.
Plase refer to D.Dimitrovs answer which show the correct way using `DateTime`

Comment: I don't understand how an answer stating that another answer is correct (and repeating some comments) could be useful.

Answer (score 0):

For this approach, I have resolved it using this formula and no need to use `datetime` for I dont have date on my data.

```
if($timeIn > $timeOut){
    $timeDiff = 24 - abs(strtotime($timeIn)/60)/60;
    $timeDiff += $timeOut;
}else{
    $timeDiff = strtotime($timeIn) - strtotime($timeOut);
    $timeDiff = ($timeDiff/60)/60;
}
```

Hope this well help the others.